# How to pass an array to a function that uses sizeof?

Tags: c++, arduino

This is what I use to get the length of an array:

```
sizeof(counts) / sizeof(unsigned long)
```

Now I want to make a simple function out of it like:

```
int length(unsigned long* input)
{
    return (sizeof(input) / sizeof(unsigned long));
}


unsigned long array[3];

sizeof(array) = 12
sizeof(unsigned long) = 4
sizeof(array) / sizeof(unsigned long) = 3

lenght(array) = 1
```

Inside length() sizeof(array) returns 4

The compiler will complain when I change the function to:

```
int length(unsigned long input)
{
  return (sizeof(input) / sizeof(unsigned long));
}
```

I'm either stoned or just dumb, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not realizing that since `input` is an `unsigned long *`, then `sizeof(input)` is equivalent to `sizeof(unsigned long *)`, which is always the same value, whether this is a pointer to one, or a billion unsigned long. `sizeof` is a ***compile-time constant***, that's evaluated at compile time to the size of its argument.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx

Comment: ***what am I doing wrong?*** Using a c-array instead of std:array. However I assume you are in class and are not permitted to use std::array.

Comment: I'm not in class, been programming for quite a while but this just stumped me and I know what I've been doing wrong now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are neither stoned or dumb (well, unless....). The `sizeof` operator can only be used on an array **within the scope the array was declared**. When an array is passed as a parameter, it is converted to a *pointer to the first element* of the array.

So `length` receives `input` as `unsigned long *`. What is `unsigned long *`? (hint: a pointer). What is `sizeof (a pointer)` (hint: generally 4-bytes on x86 or 8-bytes on x86_64).

So while you can use `sizeof(input) / sizeof(unsigned long)` **in the scope** where `input` was declared as an array, e.g. `unsigned long array[3];`, once it is passed as a parameter -- it is simply a pointer.

Comment: This is on Arduino, I simply forgot pointers return the size of the first element. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Just make sure you are clear that when `input` is passed in `int length(unsigned long* input)`, `input` is a pointer to the first element of `input`. It does NOT matter what type (e.g. `char, int, long`, etc...) because the `sizeof (a pointer)` will be the same for all. It is the number of bytes required to store any pointer that is returned, not the number of bytes related to the `type` of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t length(T (&input)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Or just use `std::extent`

Comment: I would mark length() function as the constexpr function. Then you can write something like this. int xyz[100]; int abc[length(xyz)];

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the array is decayed to a pointer to its first element.
However, you can do something like that :

```
template<size_t N>
void foo(int (&array)[N]) {
    for(auto elem : array) use(elem);
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t length(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Else you can use `std::array` that is the proper way to do static array in C++

Comment: I believe you need to pass the array to the function template by reference to prevent it from decaying to a pointer.

Comment: My god, I forgot it ^^, sorry I fixed it

Comment: std::array is not really used on Arduino, I forgot pointers return the size of the first element. Thanks!